# SQL SELECT Statement - Select record based on number of matches from second table

Tags: sql

This is my first question so sorry in advance for breaking any unspoken rules. I currently am trying to retrieve categories from a `InventoryCategory` table using the primary key from the `InventoryItem` table.

Since an item can have one or more categories, the `InventoryCategory` table holds the `ItemCode`, `CategoryCode`, and `IsPrimary` (to define which category is primary category and is TRUE/FALSE type)

I really need to use the main category for all items with only one category and the non-primary category for items with two categories. I am trying to use a CASE statement to output the right value as a named `ParentCategory` field but having tough time.

Currently, I just have `WHERE IC.IsPrimary = 1` since I haven't been able to figure out how to query the `ItemCode` to return # of `CategoryCodes` and select non-primary category based on that. I tried doing a COUNT but it always returns 1 and keep striking out.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    BillToCode, POSWorkstationID, 
    InvoiceDate, ItemName, 
    CategoryCode, 
    SUM(QtySales) QtySales, 
    SUM(Sales) Sales, 
    SUM(QtyReturns) QtyReturns, 
    SUM([Returns]) [Returns], 
    WarehouseCode   
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         CI.BillToCode, CI.WarehouseCode, 
         CI.POSWorkstationID, CI.InvoiceDate, 
         IC.CategoryCode, ii.ItemName, 
         CASE 
            WHEN CI.Type IN ('Invoice', 'Opening Invoice') 
              THEN CID.QuantityShipped 
              ELSE 0 
         END AS QtySales, 
         CASE 
            WHEN CI.Type IN ('Invoice', 'Opening Invoice') 
              THEN CID.ExtPriceRate 
              ELSE 0 
         END AS Sales, 
         CASE 
            WHEN CI.Type IN ('Credit Memo', 'Opening Credit', 'Gift Card', 'Gift Certificate') 
              THEN CID.QuantityShipped 
              ELSE 0 
         END AS QtyReturns,
         CASE 
            WHEN CI.Type IN ('Credit Memo', 'Opening Credit', 'Gift Card', 'Gift Certificate') 
              THEN CID.ExtPriceRate 
              ELSE 0 
         END AS [Returns]
     FROM 
         CustomerInvoice CI            
     INNER JOIN 
         Customer C ON CI.BillToCode = C.CustomerCode            
     INNER JOIN 
         CustomerInvoiceDetail CID ON CI.InvoiceCode = CID.InvoiceCode
     INNER JOIN 
         InventoryItem ii ON CID.ItemCode = ii.ItemCode    
     INNER JOIN 
         InventoryCategory IC ON CID.ItemCode = IC.ItemCode
     WHERE 
         (CI.IsBatch = 0 OR CI.IsBatch IS NULL) 
         AND CI.IsPosted = 1 
         AND CI.[Type] = 'Invoice' 
         AND CI.IsVoided = 0 
         AND IC.IsPrimary = 1) Items        
GROUP BY 
    POSWorkstationID, BillToCode, ItemName, InvoiceDate, CategoryCode, WarehouseCode
```

Comment: what if you split it into two queries: one to get those items in one category `UNION` another query to get the items that are in two+ categories?

Comment: Which category do you want to get is there are three or more?

Comment: One of the spoken (as opposed to unspoken) "rules" of SQL questions is that 1. sample data, and 2. expected result, make it vastly easier to a. communicate your requirements, and b. for the community to answer you. e.g. Do you want 2 columns of category? or 2 rows? and Diego's question: What happens if there are more than 2?

Comment: tips on how to ask a question: basics: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and for more info:  http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ (note the "sample code and data")

Comment: That's a case expression, not a case statement...

Comment: @Used_By_Already 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

If the IsPrimary field is 0 for the non-primary row, you could do a `SELECT MIN` statement. See below:

```
SELECT BillToCode        
, POSWorkstationID    
, InvoiceDate
, ItemName           
, CategoryCode
, SUM(QtySales) QtySales          
, SUM(Sales) Sales          
, SUM(QtyReturns) QtyReturns          
, SUM([Returns]) [Returns]       
, WarehouseCode   

FROM (          

SELECT CI.BillToCode
, CI.WarehouseCode
, CI.POSWorkstationID
, CI.InvoiceDate
, IC.CategoryCode
, ii.ItemName  
, CASE WHEN CI.Type IN ('Invoice', 'Opening Invoice') THEN CID.QuantityShipped ELSE 0 END AS QtySales            
, CASE WHEN CI.Type IN ('Invoice', 'Opening Invoice') THEN CID.ExtPriceRate ELSE 0 END AS Sales          
, CASE WHEN CI.Type IN ('Credit Memo', 'Opening Credit', 'Gift Card', 'Gift Certificate') THEN CID.QuantityShipped ELSE 0 END AS QtyReturns          
, CASE WHEN CI.Type IN ('Credit Memo', 'Opening Credit', 'Gift Card', 'Gift Certificate') THEN CID.ExtPriceRate ELSE 0 END AS [Returns]      

FROM CustomerInvoice CI            
INNER JOIN Customer C ON CI.BillToCode = C.CustomerCode            
INNER JOIN CustomerInvoiceDetail CID ON CI.InvoiceCode = CID.InvoiceCode
INNER JOIN InventoryItem ii ON CID.ItemCode = ii.ItemCode    
INNER JOIN InventoryCategory IC ON CID.ItemCode = IC.ItemCode
WHERE (CI.IsBatch = 0 OR CI.IsBatch IS NULL) 
AND CI.IsPosted = 1 
AND CI.[Type] = 'Invoice' AND CI.IsVoided = 0 
AND IC.IsPrimary = (SELECT MIN(IsPrimary) FROM InventoryCategory ICi WHERE ICi.ItemCode = IC.ItemCode)
) Items        

GROUP BY POSWorkstationID, BillToCode, ItemName, InvoiceDate, CategoryCode, WarehouseCode
```

Comment: Thanks, @wyatt-shipman ! That worked much better. I also had to change MIN(IsPrimary) to MIN(IsPrimary+0) since I was getting an operand error for trying to MIN a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your InventoryCategory data looks something like this:

```
ItemCode CategoryCode IsPrimary
abc      def          1
abc      xyz          0
abc      123          0
```

Instead of joining to that table, used a "derived table" (subquery) such as this:

```
inner join (
            select
                  ItemCode
                , max(case when IsPrimary = 1 then CategoryCode end) PrimCategory
                , max(case when IsPrimary = 0 then CategoryCode end) SecCategory
                , min(CategoryCode) as tertiaryCategory
            from InventoryCategory 
            group by ItemCode
           ) IC ON CID.ItemCode = IC.ItemCode
```

Then in your main select clause you can use this (or a case expression perhaps):

```
COALESCE(IC.PrimCategory,IC.SecCategory,IC.tertiaryCategory) as CategoryCode
```

Comment: The answer was based on the assumption you wanted 2 columns for category, but you have since indicated you want 2 rows; so this probably isn't the solution for you - but it is an alternative approach you may find helpful at some point.